# How to configure Retrofit to convert success/error responses

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Server sends response in case of success (code 2xx):

```
{
    "user":"User",
    "age":16
}
```

And in case of fail (4xx) the following Json is sent in `errorBody`:

```
{
    "errorMessage":"Server is not working",
    "action":{
         ...
    }
}
```

How can I can I configure Retrofit so that it automatically converts responses based on success/fail. 
**Note**: I am using JavaRx v2.2.0 and Retrofit v2.4.0

My method to make API call is like:

```
@GET("/screens/home")
Single<HomeResponse> getHome(@Query("langCode") String langCode);
```

I tried to encapsulate `HomeResponse` (my own java class) with `Response` (Retrofit's). However, I did not get I want.

```
@GET("/screens/home")
Single<Reponse<HomeResponse>> getHome(@Query("langCode") String langCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your **HomeResponse** class with all property which you want from success and error like below.

```
class HomeResponse {
    String user;
    String age;
    String errorMessage;
    Action action;
}
```

**Action** will be your another class. 
You just check of errorMessage null or not at a time of response.

Answer (score 1):

you can make pojo class using this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), 
write both success & error response fields in json which you are getting merge both json and make a pojo class

you can check the response by `status` or something which define that this is `error` response

**EDIT**

see this

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MyApiResponse {

@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private String user;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private Integer age;
@SerializedName("errorMessage")
@Expose
private String errorMessage;
@SerializedName("action")
@Expose
private Action action;

public String getUser() {
return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
this.user = user;
}

public Integer getAge() {
return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
this.age = age;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

public Action getAction() {
return action;
}

public void setAction(Action action) {
this.action = action;
}

}
```

Comment: Error is sent in errorBody. I want Retrofit to convert it automatically, not by myself everytime because there are lots of API call methods in my App.

Comment: see my edit, here if you get error than `errorMessage` will not `null` otherwise it will `null`

**Suggestion** : if you are getting same response for error in all `api` than you can make it as `BaseModel` and extends it in all `model` for all `apis`

Comment: In case of error I do not get error response directly. It comes in Response class's errorBody

Comment: i'm not getting you

Answer (score 0):

For this form of response data rules, it's better to create a base response class:

```
class BaseResponse {
    String errorMessage;
    Action action;
    //ingore getters setters
}
```

And make your other response classes extend it

```
class HomeResponse extend BaseResponse{
    String user;
    String age;
}

class OtherResp extend BaseResponse{
    String otherField;
}
```